# Как подружить ie8 c css3?

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, internet-explorer, html5

ie8 не понимает свойства skew.
Пишу так, используя примочку с сайта:

http://useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator

```
.frame {
display: none;
cursor:pointer;
position: absolute;
left: 14px;
top: 0;
width: 88%;
height: 89%;
border: 5px solid #1a8e19;
-webkit-transform: skew(-7deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-7deg);
-o-transform: skew(-7deg);
-ms-transform: skew(-7deg);
transform: skewX(-7deg);
/* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=-0.12278456090290474, M21=-0.12278456090290474, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
}
```

Все равно не видит (при навведении зеленый прямоуголник должен быть полусогнутым вправо)
http://testjay.esy.es/catalog_tea.html

Answer (score 1):

Через только если писать на js. Посмотрю плагины, если не отписался - не смог найти.